# Sort String and parse to list

Tags: java, sorting, parsing

I have a string that has names and rating, I want to sort them in a highest to lower manner based off the rating. The rating will always be a positive number.

The string looks like this:

```
"john;q=1, david;q=0, scott, robert, bob;q=0.5"
```

If a name has no value, it should be last in the sorted order. I would also like to split this string into a list. So the above string should be parsed into:

```
["john", "bob", "david", "scott", "robert"]
```

Note: the order for "scott" and "robert" should be as it appears in the original string

This is how I am doing it currently:

```
private List<String> parseString(final String str) {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    String[] acceptHeaders = str.replace(" ", "").split(",");

    for (String header : acceptHeaders) {
        if (header.contains(";")) {
            int equalIndex = header.indexOf("=");
            String value = header.substring(equalIndex + 1, header.length());
            String name = header.substring(0, equalIndex-2);
            if (map.containsKey(value)) {
                List<String> val = map.get(value);
                val.add(name);
                map.put(value, val);
            } else {
                List<String> val = new ArrayList<>();
                val.add(name);
                map.put(value, val);
            }
        } else {
            if (!map.containsKey("-1")) {
                map.put("-1", new ArrayList<>());
            }
            List<String> val = map.get("-1");
            val.add(header);
            map.put("-1", val);
        }
    }

    return map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());;
}
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this in java?

Comment: Comma-separated list of values, where values have an optional `;q=` and a number in range 0-1. That looks lie the value of an HTTP [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header, and lo and behold, you have a local variable named `acceptHeaders`. Why are you trying to call this something else? --- Anyway, you said *"no value, it should be last in the sorted order"*, but the HTTP specification says *"When not present, the **default value is 1**"*, which means that it should be sorted **first**, together with any value with an explicit `;q=1` quality value.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, but do you have any suggestions on how I can clean up my code in order to achieve what I am doing?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See this:

```
    TreeMap<Float, String> map = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    for (String user : input.split(", ")) {
        String[] split = user.split(";q=");
        map.put(split.length == 1 ? (map.lastKey() - 1f) : Float.valueOf(split[1]), split[0]);
    }
    return map.values();
```

Any better solution than this?

Comment: This looks great. Thanks!

Comment: edited :) more concise by taking help of map.lastKey() method from TreeMap

Comment: Doesn't work when: 1) There is more than one value with the same q-value. 2) The first value doesn't have a q-value. 3) There is more than one value without a q-value.

Comment: #1: split still gives you original String.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Comparator {

public static class NewClass implements  Comparable<NewClass>{
    public String s;
    public float rating;

    public NewClass(String s) {
        String[] split = s.split(";q=");
        this.s = split[0];
        if(split.length > 1){
            this.rating = Float.parseFloat(split[1]);
        }else{
            this.rating = -1f;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(NewClass o) {
        return Float.compare(o.rating, this.rating); //sorting in descending order
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] input = new String[]{"john;q=1", "david;q=0", "scott", "robert", "bob;q=0.5"};
    ArrayList<NewClass> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String s : input){
        items.add(new NewClass(s));
    }
    Collections.sort(items);
    String[] output = new String[input.length];
    int count= 0;
    for(NewClass item : items){
        output[count++] = item.s;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
}
```

I created a new class and used Comparable Interface to sort the items using rating. If rating is not given, I assumed it to be -1. you can have any value here.

Comment: `compareTo()` is wrong. Should be `return Float.compare(o.rating, this.rating); // descending`. The comment is to document that the reversal of `o` and `this` is intentional, and that is causes a descending sort order.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert all the strings to an ArrarList
2. Sort that ArrayList using Collections.sort() or equivalent in Java 8. Pass a Comparator in sort() method and in compare() method of that Comparator, write logic like determine the rating and accordingly return.

I am not sure whether this will be cleaner but this approach came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Class named, Client/Student.
2. Parse String and create Client/Student object and put then in a list `ArrayList<DevStudent> devList`.
3. Then sort them using `Collections.sort()`

DevStuden class:

```
class DevStudent{
    String name;
    double rating;
    
    public DevStudent(String name,double rating){
        this.name = name;
        this.rating = rating;
    }   
}
```

Sort using Collections.sort:

```
List<DevStudent> devList = new ArrayList<DevStudent>();
//populate devList
//then sort
Collections.sort(devList, new Comparator<DevStudent>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(DevStudent c1, DevStudent c2) {
      return Double.compare(c2.rating, c1.rating);
    }
});
```